# How to make a responsive an absolute position?

Tags: html, css, css-position, responsive, absolute

I made a map  tag on an image when clicking on that specific part of the map it will lead the user to a specific URL  so it works on large screens but on medium and small screens the position of absolute changes its position in another position.

in CSS I make a bunch of elements with tags that are correctly positioned in an image.

```
        <div className="Afghan-map ">
                <img src={map} className="Afg-map mw-100" alt="afg-map" />

                <a
                    href="http://192.168.90.4/users/"
                    title="Badghis"
                    className="badghis province"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noreferrer"
                />
                <a
                    href="http://192.168.70.3/users/"
                    title="Balkh"
                    className="balkh province"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noreferrer"
                />
                <a
                    href="http://192.168.50.5/users/"
                    title="Jallal Abad"
                    className="jallal-abbad province"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noreferrer"
                />
                <a
                    href="http://192.168.80.1/users/"
                    title="Herat"
                    className="herat province"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noreferrer"
                />
                <a
                    href="http://192.168.60.2/users/"
                    title="Kabul"
                    className="kabul province"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noreferrer"
                />
            </div>
```

#this is my CSS code

```
.Afghan-map {
.Afg-map {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
.province {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

.balkh {
    left: 43.89%;
    top: 21.71%;
    width: 8.33%;
    height: 10.71%;
}

.jallal-abbad {
    left: 59%;
    top: 44.86%;
    width: 4.44%;
    height: 4.29%;
}

.badghis {
    left: 30.78%;
    top: 33.57%;
    width: 9.33%;
    height: 10.86%;
}

.kabul {
    left: 54.89%;
    top: 42%;
    width: 4.33%;
    height: 5.29%;
}

.herat {
    left: 24.11%;
    top: 42.43%;
    width: 9.33%;
    height: 15.71%;
}
```

}

Comment: Hello, without the CSS styles for your example we cannot answer you. The best would be to edit your question to include a runnable snippet so we can test it

Comment: You mean the clickable parts just don't correspond to the good parts of the map, or they are all over the place? Note that the `<a>` tags are not self closing tags, they should look like `<a></a>` instead of `<a/>`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to put your code on Codepen but the CSS style is not working.
To solve the problem, your could try `transform:translate` with different `@media`

Comment: yes, I solved this by media query, which helped me position it every query changes.